# "Unable to load the specified metadata resource" ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am getting the error "`Unable to load the specified metadata resource`". I am new to asp.net and am following this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-2

I am using Visual studio 2012 and ms server 2012 unlike the tutorial and I chose new website not web app when starting the site.

I created a entity data source control and then created a ADO.NET entity data entry with the database provided. then when i try to use the control i get the error.

I read it could be the connection string so here is mine. I have spent hours trying to fix it, can someone help?

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString=" metadata=res://*/Data_Access.EDM_Commerce.csdl| res://*/Data_Access.EDM_Commerce.ssdl| res://*/Data_Access.EDM_Commerce.msl; provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=OWEN;initial catalog=Commerce.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework';" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have tried changing my connection string to this :

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="
         metadata=res://*/;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=OWEN;initial catalog=Commerce.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework';" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I do this I don't get the error but the DefaultContainerName has no options.

thanks.